# Python: Break while loop

Tags: python

I am using a code that takes an input of image files (can be any number in the source folder) and processes them and then saves the files. I am using a `while loop` to save the files. But the problem I am facing is that once the loop processes all the images and saves them, it starts all over again. How can I break the loop once all the images in the source folder have been processed and saved?

The code I am using is:

```
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

# loop over the image paths
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["images"]))

#open images in a sequence
imagePaths.sort()

i =1
while True:
   for imagePath in imagePaths:
       # load the image and resize it to (1) reduce detection time
       # and (2) improve detection accuracy
       image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
       image = imutils.resize(image, width=min(700, image.shape[1]))
       orig = image.copy()

       # detect people in the image
        (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4),
        padding=(8, 8), scale=1.05)

       # draw the original bounding boxes
       for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
             cv2.rectangle(orig, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

       # apply non-maxima suppression to the bounding boxes using a
       # fairly large overlap threshold to try to maintain overlapping
       # boxes that are still people
       rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
       pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)

       # draw the final bounding boxes
       for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
              cv2.rectangle(image, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

       # show some information on the number of bounding boxes
       filename = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
       print("[INFO] {}: {} original boxes, {} after suppression".format(
        filename, len(rects), len(pick)))

       cv2.imwrite('%d.png' % (i),image)
       i +=1
```

Comment: Why is it in an infinite `while` loop at all?

Comment: while True == infinite

Comment: You could use break to break out of the loop. The loop makes no sense here, though.

Comment: The source files can vary in number and I didn't know how to make it stop when all the source files have been processed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for imagePath in imagePaths:` already loops over your data and processes everything. There's no reason for it to be nested within another loop. Remove that loop.

```
...
imagePaths.sort()

i = 1
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    ...
```

Comment: I tried doing this: `i = 1` `for imagePath in imagePaths: ....` and I was saving the file `cv2.imwrite('%d.png' % (i),image)`. It still keeps looping

Comment: @NikhileshSharma - Are you sure you saved the changed script?

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    for ...:
         // your code
         // your code...
    break  // terminate while loop
```

Add `break` at the end of your for loop, it will terminate your current `while True` loop

In you case, you don't need `while True` at all. The for loop iterates all your images already.